# colorbar in 3D GIF

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d, colorbar

So i am trying to plot the movement of particles in a box, and want to visualize the velocity with a colorbar. My Code looks like this

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
div = make_axes_locatable(ax)
cax = div.append_axes('right', size='15%', pad='5%')
tx = ax.set_title('Timestep 0')

def update(t):
    tx.set_text('Timestep {0}'.format(t))
    X,Y,Z,u,v,w=np.random.rand(6,6)
    track = ax.scatter(X, Y, Z, s=1, c=np.linalg.norm([u, v, w], axis=0), cmap=plt.cm.get_cmap('inferno'))
    cax.cla()
    plt.colorbar(track,cax=cax)
    return track, ax

if __name__ == '__main__':
    anim = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=np.arange(10), interval=100, blit=False)
    anim.save('ClusterTrajectories.gif', dpi=150, writer='imagemagick')
```

However, if i run that, i get following error

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
  File "/home/itvmi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 1007, in save
    anim._init_draw()
  File "/home/itvmi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 1490, in _init_draw
    self._draw_frame(next(self.new_frame_seq()))
  File "/home/itvmi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 1512, in _draw_frame
    self._drawn_artists = self._func(framedata, *self._args)
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in update
  File "/home/itvmi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2262, in colorbar
    ret = gcf().colorbar(mappable, cax = cax, ax=ax, **kw)
  File "/home/itvmi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1602, in colorbar
    cb = cbar.colorbar_factory(cax, mappable, **kw)
  File "/home/itvmi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/colorbar.py", line 1347, in colorbar_factory
    cb = Colorbar(cax, mappable, **kwargs)
  File "/home/itvmi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/colorbar.py", line 926, in __init__
    ColorbarBase.__init__(self, ax, **kw)
  File "/home/itvmi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/colorbar.py", line 325, in __init__
    self.config_axis()
  File "/home/itvmi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/colorbar.py", line 360, in config_axis
    ax.yaxis.set_label_position(self.ticklocation)
  File "/home/itvmi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py", line 1811, in set_label_position
    raise ValueError(msg)
ValueError: Position accepts only [ 'top' | 'bottom' ]
```

unfortunately i have no idea what to do now, as i don't use a label. I have seen other examples where this worked, but it was not a 3d axis...
It would be great, if someone has an idea what to do, thank you in advance.

Comment: It would be great if you could provide a [mcve], i.e. a code where there are no undefined variable and which is hence runnable. This makes it much easier to locate the problem.

Comment: You may easily check if you created a [mcve] by copying the code from the question and running it. If it then produces the same error as you want to ask about, you're done. This however does not seem to be the case here.

Comment: thanks for the advice, it now produces the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess `mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1` has never been tested to work with 3D plots. At least the problem here comes from `make_axes_locatable`. If instead you create a normal axes like

```
cax = fig.add_subplot(1,30,30)
```

it works fine.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
cax = fig.add_subplot(1,30,30)

tx = ax.set_title('Timestep 0')

def update(t):
    tx.set_text('Timestep {0}'.format(t))
    X,Y,Z,u,v,w=np.random.rand(6,6)
    track = ax.scatter(X, Y, Z, s=1, c=np.linalg.norm([u, v, w], axis=0), cmap=, cmap='inferno')
    cax.cla()
    plt.colorbar(track,cax=cax)
    return track, ax

if __name__ == '__main__':
    anim = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=np.arange(10), interval=100, blit=False)
    anim.save('ClusterTrajectories.gif', dpi=150, writer='imagemagick')
```

Or, to avoid overlapping, one may use `GridSpec` as

```
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec

gs = GridSpec(1,30)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(gs[:-1], projection='3d')
cax = fig.add_subplot(gs[-1])
```